# PHP DOMDocument - How to force using numeric character references or entities, not UTF8

Tags: php, xml, dom, encoding, domdocument

I have a `DOMDocument` to which I am appending some nodes.
In some of the text contents, there are special characters as ©, –, δ etc...

My goal is when inserting those characters in the `DOMDocument`, that they will be converted to numeric character references (NCR) or entities, respectively:

```
© - &#x000A9;
– - &#x2013;
δ - &#x3B4;
```

Comment: My question is: Why do you think you need it? Whatever system is consuming your output must be able to understand HTML or XML correctly and be able to use the Unicode charset internally. There is not very much use in general to use NCRs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the encoding to a character set that doesn't contain those characters, for example `us-ascii`.

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('<foo>©</foo>');
$dom->encoding = 'us-ascii';
print($dom->saveXML());
```

leads to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<foo>&#169;</foo>
```

To change the entities into hex you can apply something like

```
preg_replace('/&#([0-9]+);/e', '\'&#x\'.strtoupper(dechex($1)).\';\'', $xml);
```

to the XML output.

Comment: I like your answer very much, it is close to what I need. But what is the real encoding of those special characters to get what I described, ex: `© - &#x000A9;`

Comment: I don't think you can get it to use numeric entities in hex, it will always use decimal. If you really need to have them in hex you will have to go through the XML afterwards and replace them with their hex equivalent.

Comment: Hm, any idea on how to do that? I mean, I know how to go through, but how to convert them later?

Comment: I have extended the answer with this.

Comment: Thanks, but what I need as output is an XML, so I will have to create andother $xmlon which I will load the one with preg_replace. And apparently, this is not working.

Comment: What do you mean? The encoding into entities happens precisely when you generate an XML string from the DOM (or save it to a file etc.). Internally the DOMDocument (or more precise the elements etc.) will always keep the text data as unicode. So if you do the preg_replace and parse it into another DOMDocument you are back to square on, and there is nothing that can change that.

Comment: In fact, my final product will be a xml file that I am generatin with `$dom->save(/myFile);` So, your idea will be to first save the xml in a string like `$xml_string = $dom->saveXML();` and then run the `preg_replace` there and save again this string in a xml file ?